# How to bind a jagged array into DataGridView?

Tags: c#, arrays, .net, winforms, datagridview

I have 2D array with different types of data(int, string, float).

How do i bind it to data grid view?

Or converting it to data View or BindingList or DataTable and then bind it to datagridview?

Edits:
Object[,] is completely dynamic data(Different no of rows, columns, datatypes., Like dump data): (Excel sheets)

[0,x] "kjslwe" 3  "w" 45  "erer" 643  "reew" "54" 56  34

[1,y] 23      "e"  1 "sf" 123213 "ds" 343433

Comment: What is the data structure? Share a sample of data. Also if it's a winforms question, remove asp.net tag.

Comment: I have edited the question adding extra details. It is a 2D object array that stores multiple types of data in rows and columns(can be null at few columns)

Comment: Why bound? You can create rows on your own by parsing the data in your code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are not using a [`2D Array`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/arrays/multidimensional-arrays?WT.mc_id=DT-MVP-5003235), you are using a [`Jagged Array`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/arrays/jagged-arrays?WT.mc_id=DT-MVP-5003235). A jagged array is an array whose elements are arrays. The elements of a jagged array can be of different dimensions and sizes. A jagged array is sometimes called an "array of arrays."

To show a jagged array in `DataGridView`, you can first calculate the number of columns which you need and set [`ColumnCount`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.datagridview.columncount?WT.mc_id=DT-MVP-5003235&view=netframework-4.8) property of grid. Then add rows using an overload of [`Add`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.datagridviewrowcollection.add?WT.mc_id=DT-MVP-5003235&view=netframework-4.8) method of [`Rows`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.datagridview.rows?WT.mc_id=DT-MVP-5003235&view=netframework-4.8) collection of grid which accepts `param object[]`. For example:

```
object[][] data = new object[][]{ 
        new object[] {"kjslwe", 3, "w", 45, "erer", 643, "reew", "54", 56, 34},
        new object [] {23, "e", 1, "so", 123213, "ds", 343433}
};

var columns = data.Max(x => x.Count());         /* Calculate number of columns */
grid.ColumnCount = columns;                     /* Set column count of grid   */
data.ToList().ForEach(x => grid.Rows.Add(x));   /* Add rows                    */
```

[image]

In the above example, I also set these properties:

```
grid.AllowUserToAddRows = false;
grid.AllowUserToDeleteRows = false;
grid.AutoSizeColumnsMode = DataGridViewAutoSizeColumnsMode.AllCellsExceptHeader;
```