# Load a list from an array

Tags: c#, arrays, winforms, list, visual-studio-2010

I have a program that is working except that my data is contained in an array; however, I have found out from you people that I cannot load a dataGridView from an array.
If I had code like this, how would I load a List for the source of the dataGridView1...

```
        // Load some date to indicate what I'm trying to do.

        int nColName = 0;
        int nColNumberOfOccurances = 1;
        int nColTotalTime = 2;
        int nColAverageTime = 3;
        string[,] strMyArray = new string[2,4];

        // load array with test data
        for (int i = 0; i < strMyArray.Length; i++)
        {
            switch (i)
            {
                case 0:
                 strMyArray.SetValue("file1.log".ToString(), i, nColName);
                 strMyArray.SetValue("10".ToString(), i, nColNumberOfOccurances);
                 strMyArray.SetValue("8989".ToString(), i, nColTotalTime);
                 strMyArray.SetValue("898.9".ToString(), i, nColAverageTime);
                 break;
                case 1:
                 strMyArray.SetValue("file2.log".ToString(), i, nColName);
                 strMyArray.SetValue("5".ToString(), i, nColNumberOfOccurances);
                 strMyArray.SetValue("4494.5".ToString(), i, nColTotalTime);
                 strMyArray.SetValue("898.9".ToString(), i, nColAverageTime);
                    break;
            }

        }

        // convert an array like the above into a List so that I can say...
       // myNewListFromArray = strMyArray
      //  dataGridView1.DataSource = myNewListFromArray;
```

Comment: You can load a datagrid view from a `List` if you bind the `ItemSource` to the datacontext. All you would then need to do is use the `LINQ` expression `.ToList()` on your array and set it as the datacontext.

Comment: @JayGould There is no `ToList()` method for multidimensional arrays

Comment: @MongZhu oops, missed that detail. Ignore my comment above :-)

Comment: can you change the situation that it is a `string [ , ]` array?

Comment: Mong Zhu; if you can provide an example of using an array that allows me create one that provides the functionality of creating an array who's rows are designated at run time and who's count of rows is stated at design time and is empty. Then allows the resultant array to be scanned and the missing data be set by something like SetValue.

Comment: I'm giving up for the moment and will come back when understand more. Thanks all for your information it has lead to more research.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Arrays works with `DataGridView`. Your problems is - you using two dimensional array which cannot be used as DataSource.

Instead of array, create a class with properties which represent your data.
Note: **important to use a property**, because `DataGridView` binding works with properties only.

```
public class MyData
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string NumberOfOccurances { get; set; }
    public string TotalTime { get; set; }
    public string AverageTime { get; set; }
}
```

Then use this class in the List

```
var list = new List<MyData>
{
    new MyData 
    { 
        Name = "file1.log",
        NumberOfOccurances = "10",
        TotalTime = "8989",
        AverageTime = "898.9"
    },
    new MyData 
    { 
        Name = "file2.log",
        NumberOfOccurances = "5",
        TotalTime = "4494.5",
        AverageTime = "898.9"
    },
}

dataGridView1.DataSource = list;
```

Comment: The key point here is the **class** with **properties** (not fields). The list is not strongly necessary, array of class also works.